# Angular, UI Router, Nested Navigation, and Tabs Issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a navigation system using Angular, ui-router, and tabs. I pretty much have it working, but am having some strange behavior.

There's a top level navigation in the form of a navbar at the top. Routing defaults to 'dashboard'. At the same 'level' of 'dashboard' is 'recordings'. Inside 'recordings', there's a secondary nav in the form of tabs. One tab is a search form, the other is a results set. When submitting the form, it should switch to the results tab. Clicking on the tabs themselves should take you to the corresponding view. And clicking on the top level navigation (dashboard,logs) should also take you to the correct state.

Issues include:

- Active state of tabs only applies after clicking on tab twice. Initially it applies active
- Inconsistent behavior with top level navigation. Sometimes requires two clicks as well

Here's a stripped down plunker of my setup.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FS6J6V4fu9Zz9VxSSQXQ?p=preview)

Routing

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

$stateProvider
  .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
      'main': {
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.tpl.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('recordings', {
    url: '/recordings',
    views: {
      'main': {
        controller: 'RecordingsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'recordings.tpl.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('recordings.search', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/search',
    views: {
      'recordings': {
        controller: 'SearchCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'search.tpl.html'
      },
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'searchContent.tpl.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('recordings.search.form', {
    url: '/form',
    controller: 'SearchCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'form.tpl.html'
  })
  .state('recordings.search.results', {
    url: '/results',
    controller: 'ResultsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'results.tpl.html'
  });
```

Tab code

```
$scope.tabs = [
  {
    heading: 'Search',
    state: 'recordings.search.form',
    active: false
  },
  {
    heading: 'Results',
    state: 'recordings.search.results',
    active: false
  }
];
$scope.go = function(route){
    $state.go(route);
};

$scope.active = function(route){
    return $state.is(route);
};

$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
    console.log('yay');
    $scope.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        tab.active = $scope.active(tab.route);
    });
});
```

Tab view

```
<tabset>
  <tab
    ng-repeat="t in tabs"
    heading="{{t.heading}}"
    ng-click="$state.go(t.state)"
    active="t.active">
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: How did you solved this issues?